# What would be a word describing the connection between two seemingly unconnected things?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the invisible connection between seeming unconnected things. Like the area below the surface connecting an island chain, but that could potentially relate to people/ relationships as well. The closest things I've thought of is entanglement.

ie. a single work for degrees of separation

looking for something with more of a pulse than tie or bond. Like synapse, but not just for nerves.

Sentence: Everyone in the room was working independently, but could feel each other's humanity through _____.

Comment: Hi Sid, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! It would be really helpful if you could provide at least one, but preferably several, complete sentences where you might use this word, together with any necessary context.

Comment: You could finish your sentence with *a shared intake of breath*. You island examples could be connected *by a pathway of broken waves*, suggestive of the reef that lies beneath them. Personally, I think you might get more milage from a specific and concrete description of what the hidden link causes on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

**Synchronicity**

> The simultaneous occurrence of events which appear significantly related but have no discernible causal connection.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synchronicity)

```
As the show progresses, one starts to get the feeling the lightning is happening in synchronicity with the music.
```

Comment: [Jung](https://www.carl-jung.net/synchronicity.html)

Answer (score 0):

**bond**:

something that binds, fastens, confines, or holds together.

[Look it up here if you wish](http://dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

a **tie**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tie)

n

> a connection or relationship between people, or a connection a person
>   has with a place, interest, activity

As in:

Unlikely ties brought these peoples together.

Answer (score 0):

This one is specific to people (though not a single word): ***dotted line***

ODO:

> **[dotted line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dotted_line)**
>
> NOUN
>
> **2** An indirect, informal, or secondary line of responsibility within an organization (as represented by a dotted line on an
>   organizational chart)
>
> ‘I report to Hal Jones, our CFO, with a dotted line to the audit
>   committee’

Answer (score -1):

How about **interconnectedness**? From Lexico:

> **[interconnectedness](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/interconnectedness)**: The state of being connected with each other, e.g., ‘the interconnectedness of all things in the universe’, ‘a growing awareness of our global interconnectedness’

Your examples:

> Looking below the surface exposes the **interconnectedness** of otherwise seemingly isolated islands.
>
> A single word for degrees of separation: **interconnectedness**.
>
> Everyone in the room was working independently, but could feel each other's humanity through their **interconnectedness**.